# Should a dragonborn Draconic Bloodline sorceror have only 4 starting skill proficiencies?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, skills, sorcerer, proficiency

One of my party rolled up a dragonborn (race) Draconic Bloodline sorcerer in a session and after going through the race, class, and background (outlander), she ended up with just 4 skill proficiencies: 2 from her class, and then 2 from the background.

The other 3 players all have come out with more than this. Having never run a sorcerer before, is this the correct number of skill proficiencies? Or have I missed something here?

Comment: Can you confirm that you're using "Dragonborn sorcerer (Both race and sorceror archetype)" to refer to the Draconic Bloodline sorcerer subclass in addition to the dragonborn race?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes, a Dragonborn sorcerer only has 4 skill proficiencies: 2 from sorcerer and 2 from their background.

That said, there are only 3 classes that grant more than 2 skill proficiencies: Bard and Ranger gain 3, and Rogues get to choose 4. Having only 4 proficiencies is therefore quite common, unless your Race grants additional proficiencies, e.g. Elves (Perception), Half-Elves (Any 2) or Half-Orcs (Intimidation).

Answer (score 3):

## Yes, this is correct.

[Sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#ClassFeatures):

> **Skills:** Choose two...

[Outlander background](https://www.dndbeyond.com/backgrounds/outlander):

> **Skill Proficiencies:** Athletics, Survival.

2+2=4.

Comment: I think it’s just due to the other characters around the table having more, but that’s due to either race or class

Comment: @RichardC it helps if that kind of information is in the question; it provides context on what you’re actually asking.

Comment: Seems like OP wasn’t sure if they were missing something. What seems obvious to you may not be obvious to others, that comment about confusion is unnecessary.

Comment: I went ahead and edited out the last line as it could be read as being a bit condescending towards the OP, though hopefully it was not intended that way.